# rubymine - Could not find a JavaScript runtime error on running app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have been using rvm , ruby and rails on my ubuntu 18 machine without any problems. i installed a fresh copy of rubymine 2018 and interestingly on launching the project through the top green RUn button I get the following error that i do not get on "rails s" on terminal.

```
/home/tac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby /home/tac/RubymineProjects/rmtestapp/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
Traceback (most recent call last):
    61: from /home/tac/RubymineProjects/rmtestapp/bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    60: from /home/tac/RubymineProjects/rmtestapp/bin/rails:3:in `load'
    59: from /home/tac/RubymineProjects/rmtestapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    58: from /home/tac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    57: from /home/tac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:65:in `require'
    56: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    55: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    54: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    53: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    52: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    51: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    50: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    49: from /home/tac/RubymineProjects/rmtestapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    48: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    47: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    46: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    45: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    44: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    43: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    42: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    41: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    40: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    39: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    38: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    37: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    36: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    35: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    34: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    33: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    32: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    31: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    30: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    29: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    28: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    27: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    26: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    25: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    24: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    23: from /home/tac/RubymineProjects/rmtestapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    22: from /home/tac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    21: from /home/tac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    20: from /home/tac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    19: from /home/tac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    18: from /home/tac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    17: from /home/tac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    16: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    15: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    14: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    13: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    12: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    11: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<main>'
    10: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
     9: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
     8: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
     7: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     6: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     5: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     4: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     3: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     2: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<main>'
     1: from /home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/tac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The app runs with when launched with the terminal. With rubymine, it doesn't. I do have node and npm installed.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you manage to resolve?

Comment: Use asdf for version managing ruby